# Query Bigquery with Variables in Watson Studio

Tags: watson-studio

I want to query data from my Google Bigquery Instance in Watson Studio SPSS Modeler via a Bigquery Data Connection. The connection itself works fine. But how can I query by some Input parameter (example a user id). I see the option of running custom SQL but that doesn't work. I always get the error "CDICO2034E: The property [schema_name] must not be set when property [select_statement] is set."

Also I don't know how to use a input parameter in my SQL query.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing schema_name property?  You should not specify the schema_name property when using select_statement property, since the schema name would be specified in your select statement, for example

SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE ...

The select_statement property does not support input parameters.  Any WHERE clause filter would need to use literals.